# BeanFactoryAware?? How does it know which beanFactory to use?

Tags: java, spring

I am been trying to find a better what to do this. In Spring a lot of my classes need to load beans (objects) from XmlBeanFactory. So I put the following line into most of my classes

```
private static XmlBeanFactory beanFactory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("config.xml"))
```

Then someone posted that I should make my classes implement BeanFactoryAware that will give them instance of the bean factory, so you could call one of BeanFactory.getBean(..) methods directly...

I implement BeanFactoryAware in the classes but now I am getting

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

as I try to access the factory from my object.  am I missing something?? how does Spring know the beanFactory to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object implementing `BeanFactoryAware` should be a bean itself to have bean factory injected. It is done as part of bean processing.

Bean factory injected will be the one which instantiated the bean implementing `BeanFactoryAware`.

Answer (score 1):

That is just wrong and pertty much contradicts the entire point of Spring. If you create a new bean-factory in each object where you need it, you will also create new instances of all beans defined in your spring config (and annotations).

The whole point of Spring is to create **one** bean factory and have it create your entire object graph, through bean declarations and wiring. I would advise looking at some Spring tutorial, or if you have some other people around you who are more experienced with Spring, ask them to give you an intro.

Comment: are you saying to use BeanFactoryAware is bad?

Comment: It depends what you want to accomplish. If you just want to use the bean factory in one bean to get another bean, you should use @Autowired (or explicitly injecting, if you are using xml config). If you really NEED the bean factory, BeanFactoryAware is the way to go.